# Why recover database request archived log from the future

Tags: oracle, restore, rman

It suddenly throw error when I trying to do our monthly backup verification, it failed on recover database command with :

```
ORA-00279: change 26378396150 generated at 05/31/2023 03:52:48 needed for
thread 1
ORA-00289: suggestion : /d03/DEV/data03/archive/1_24306_875277866.dbf
ORA-00280: change 26378396150 for thread 1 is in sequence #24306
ORA-00278: log file '/d03/DEV/data03/archive/1_24305_875277866.dbf' no longer
needed for this recovery

ORA-00308: cannot open archived log
'/d03/DEV/data03/archive/1_24306_875277866.dbf'
ORA-27037: unable to obtain file status
IBM AIX RISC System/6000 Error: 2: No such file or directory
Additional information: 3
```

Which confuse me because the RMAN Backup that I'm trying to restore was from 05/30/2023, but it requesting an archived log from backup at 05/31/2023.

The backup run daily and it is Online Full Backup, I even tried to copy the archived log from 05/31/2023 but then it asked for further archive log from 06/01/2023, so it seems like it keeps asking for newer and newer archived logs. Can someone tell me how to fix this?

For information, I'm using the below command when I see the error:

> recover database using backup controlfile until cancel;

And I chose AUTO on prompt

Edit 1 :

I tried using command `until time` set to one hour before backup started (backup ran at 03:00:00) :

> recover database using backup controlfile until time '2023-06-05:02:00:00';

but it output :

```
ORA-01547: warning: RECOVER succeeded but OPEN RESETLOGS would get error below
ORA-01194: file 1 needs more recovery to be consistent
ORA-01110: data file 1: '/d03/DEV/data03/system01.dbf'
```

I tried that command two times with different backup and it resulted in the same error during `recover database` command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so in the end I ran `recover database` command without `until time` until it output error regarding non-existing "future" archive log.

```
ORA-00279: change 26378396150 generated at 05/31/2023 03:52:48 needed for
thread 1
ORA-00289: suggestion : /d03/DEV/data03/archive/1_24306_875277866.dbf
ORA-00280: change 26378396150 for thread 1 is in sequence #24306
ORA-00278: log file '/d03/DEV/data03/archive/1_24305_875277866.dbf' no longer
needed for this recovery
```

Then I noted the change number (in this case **26378396150**), reduce it by 1, and supply it to `recover database` command with `until change`.

```
recover database using backup controlfile until change 26378396149;
```

The command managed to recover the database successfully without other warning or error. I am still checking if there are any data loss but I can consider my question is answered.

Answer (score 3):

Normal behavior, you did not specify a target time for recovery, it will keep asking for newer logs, even if they do not even exist yet.

Specify the actual target time with `UNTIL` instead of using `UNTIL CANCEL`.

Comment: I see, I'll give it a try

Comment: Please see edited question, I tried it twice with different backup and it resulted in ORA-01194